# dynamic allocation of array for array of pointers

Tags: c++

when I tried to dynamically allocate an array of pointers to char, I accidently added extra parenthesis

```
  char** p = new (char*) [5];
```

and an error occured

> error: array bound forbidden after parenthesized type-id|

I don't quit understand what's wrong and what's the difference between above code and

```
char** p = new char* [5];
```

does these parenthesis alter the semantics?

Comment: It's just invalid syntax. Why can't you write `char **p = give me some pointers;`? This is the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does these parenthesis alter the semantics?

No, it alters the syntax from valid to invalid. You can't just put parentheses anywhere you like; they can only go in places where parentheses are allowed, and this isn't one.

Comment: It was possible back in pure C.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses in types can alter the meaning of the declaration; for example, `new char * [5]` is an array of 5 pointers to char, but `char (* a)[5]` is a pointer to an array of 5 chars.

On the other hand, the type declaration you wrote has no meaning, as the compiler signaled.

For examples about the (messy) C syntax for declarations and how to interpret them, see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations), and see [here](http://cdecl.org/) for a C declarations <-> English converter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way your write your code is look like you calling the overloaded version of the 'new' operator that uses to initialize the location of raw memory such as

```
   struct point
   {
       point( void ) : x( 0 ), y( 0 ) { }
       int x;
       int y;
   };

   void proc( void )
   {
       point pts[2];
       new( &pts[0] ) point[2];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> do these parenthesis alter the semantics?

Yes, the `new` operator uses a parenthesized argument to trigger "placement new" -- it's expecting what's in the parentheses to point to raw storage.

You give `new` the declaration of the object you want to allocate, only without the name, and every declaration begins with a typename.

```
// I find "inside-out, right to left" to be a helpful rule

char *a[5];       new char *[5];     // no parens, so array of 5 pointers, to char
char (*a)[5];     new char (*)[5];   // pointer to array, of char
```

That error message isn't one of the more helpful ones ever emitted by a compiler.