# Create an array of Node pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
  struct Node {
      int data;        // The data being stored at the node
      Node *next;     // Pointer to the next node
      };

int main()
{
         Node **nodeArray = new (Node*)[5];
}
```

First question:

Is the statement in main a valid way  to create an array of 5 Node * 's  ?

What is the difference between the statement in main and `Node **nodeArray = new Node*[5];`? Main currently gives me an error: array bound forbidden after parenthesized type-id|

Second question:

How would I go through the array and do a new for each one of them? I've worked with arrays and I've worked with linked lists, but putting them together seems trickier than I'd thought.

Comment: You shouldn't have the parentheses around `Node*` after `new`.

Comment: Better to use `std::vector<Node*>` (or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that you need maximum of 5 items, you should use static allocation because it's faster and you don't have to worry about deallocating the array.

```
Node* array[SOME_CONST];
for (int i=0; i < SOME_CONST; i++)
{   
   array[i] = new Node()
   cout<<array[i];
}
```

For dynamically allocated arrays is pretty much the same thing, you just have to realize the pointer new returns points to the first item in the array.

```
Node** array = new Node*[some_num];
for (int i=0; i < some_num; i++)
{
   array[i] = new Node();
}
```

Don't forget to deallocate properly:

```
for (int i=0; i < some_num; i++)
{
   delete array[i];
}
delete[] array;
```

Comment: I get an error when I try your new statement. Please look at my addition to the first question in the original post.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The () should not be there. I'll update my example.

Comment: Your dynamic array version does not compile, error on the new statement in the for loop: no match for 'operator=' in '*((* array) + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)i) * 8u))) = (Node*)operator new(8u)'|

Comment: Sorry, it's getting late and I'm getting sloppy. Try it now.

Comment: Worked like a charm,thanks. I really need to brush up on pointers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. Just loop over your 5 `Node*`s and assign to each one of them a `new Node`.  Or if you're trying to make a linked list, maybe assign each one of them to the next one of the 5.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. What does my current statement in main doing, though? I thought I just made 5 node pointers.

Comment: Yes, it makes a pointer to an array of 5 pointers to Node...but those pointers do not point to anything yet.

Comment: There is a question about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546319/dynamic-allocation-of-array-for-array-of-pointers